# `a, `b etc not giving \alpha, \beta etc in auctex

Tags: auctex

I am using Auctex in Emacs for typing mathematical documents. I am very new to emacs and tex in general. I heard it from a friend that `a will expand as \alpha and so on in auctex, but this is not happening for me. Please help

Comment: It depends on the setup in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: What should I do to get such options? @SvendTveskæg

Comment: I'm not sure. I just know that it depends on your setup file. (You should post the file contents in your question.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX anyway! ;-)

Comment: Are you sure auctex is loaded? Remember auctex is not a part of stock emacs. You have to install it and activate it.

Answer (score 6):

From the AUCTeX manual

> ### 2.5 Entering Mathematics
>
> TeX is written by a mathematician, and has always contained good support for formatting mathematical text. AUCTeX supports this tradition, by offering a special minor mode for entering text with many mathematical symbols. You can enter this mode by typing `C-c ~`.
>
> *Command*: **LaTeX-math-mode**
> (`C-c ~`) Toggle LaTeX Math mode. This is a minor mode rebinding the key `LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix` to allow easy typing of mathematical symbols. `` ` `` will read a character from the keyboard, and insert the symbol as specified in `LaTeX-math-default` and `LaTeX-math-list`. If given a prefix argument, the symbol will be surrounded by dollar signs.
>
> You can use another prefix key (instead of `` ` ``) by setting the variable `LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix`.
>
> To enable LaTeX Math mode by default, add the following in your `.emacs` file:
>
> ```
>   (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
> ```
>
> *User Option*: **LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix**
> A string containing the prefix of `LaTeX-math-mode` commands; This value defaults to `` ` ``.
>
> The string has to be a key or key sequence in a format understood by the kbd macro. This corresponds to the syntax usually used in the manuals for Emacs Emacs Lisp.
>
> The variable `LaTeX-math-list` allows you to add your own mappings.

Comment: Thank You so much, it helped, math-mode was not enabled, thats why I ran into that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.emacs` file, append the following code:

```
inoremap <buffer> `a \alpha
inoremap <buffer> `b \beta
inoremap <buffer> `c \chi
inoremap <buffer> `d \delta
inoremap <buffer> `e \varepsilon
inoremap <buffer> `f \varphi
inoremap <buffer> `g \gamma
inoremap <buffer> `h \eta
```

Restart emacs.
These should help you out to achieve what you wanted.